# Problem with Git Repository in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, git, xcode4

In my iPhone app, I am using the in-built Git repository of Xcode 4 so that all the team members can work on the same project.

Now the problem is that even after I commit my changes to the repository, It still shows modified (M) symbol in front of the committed file.

What could be wrong?

I want to ensure that once I commit the changes it should not show "M" for that file.

Is there any setting which I have to do to make it work fine?

What can be done?

Comment: Did you commit your file from Xcode, or from the command line?

Comment: @Abizern: I committed my file from Xcode

Comment: And in the panel where you entered your commit message - did you select the file to be added to the commit?

Comment: @Abizern: Yes I selected my files before committing.

Comment: Have you verified that the files are in the commit by having a look at the git logs?

Comment: No , I dont find logs related to the files which have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried commiting manually?

Comment: What does manually commit mean?

Comment: Xcode just provides an interface - Have you tried using the command line to see the status of your repository, or commit your file? Have you restarted Xcode? Have you tried to right click on the file and committed the file itself?

Comment: Yes I have tried restarting Xcode. Yes I have also tried right clicking on the file and commit the file itself. No I didnt try using command line to see the status of my repository

Comment: And the rest of my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in Git repository is a local repository only. How do you share that with your team? If you hooked that repository to GitHub, for example, you will experience problems as the implementation is not 100% reliable. I would use the command line in this case and git add/commit/push the changes. There are discussions and tutorials in the [GitHub Blog](https://github.com/blog/810-xcode-4-released-with-git-integration).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you're doing in Xcode, or how you have set up your repository all I can say is that you should check the status of your repository in the command line. Maybe your commit fails for some reason and you're not seeing the message in Xcode.

- Try `git status` to see what state your repository is in.
- Try `git add <your files>` and then `git commit` to see if you can actually commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you stage your files before committing (`git add`)? Otherwise the commit will do nothing.

Comment: What does staging mean in this case?

I generally just right click the file and click "add" under source control for the first time and then onwards I just do "Commit Changes".

Comment: Command line git has a two-step commit process.  First you identify which changed files you want to commit by staging them.  Once you have staged all files you want to commit, you commit the changes.  This allows you to cherry-pick changed files into separate commits.  Committing without first staging has no effect, as only staged changes are committed.  In contrast, Mercurial will automatically commit all changed files.  It doesn't have a staging concept (at least, not without enabling extensions).

Comment: OP's question is about Xcode's git interface, not the commandline git interface. Xcode hides git's add/commit distinction in order to present the same interface to the user for a project tracked by either SVN or git.

Comment: Xcode wouldn't be showing unstaged files as "M"odified, would it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to Push the changes in Xcode 4 to remove the "M" or modified status. If you don't have the command line mojo like most people, you can just use the functions built in as they were intended.

It won't solve your issue of sharing as it is only a local repo. I'm finding that even using Xcode 4 with an outside repo, you need to learn some command line stuff or it just isn't going to work, or at the very least kick your butt enough to make you consider giving it up.

*edit
Just to make it clear, the process for Xcode 4 is as follows:
File-->Source Control-->Commit
File-->Source Control-->Push